# Android keep intentservice running and listen for broadcasts

Tags: android

Im trying to track how many times the "SCREEN_ON" is triggered without the user starting the app. The app itself shows a single activity with some charts and info nothing more. I created a small test but i think it's not the correct way because it's draining my battery.

I got a broadcast receiver "BOOT_COMPLETED" that starts a sticky IntentService that is registering the "SCREEN_ON" broadcast receiver with a never ending loop to catch to broadcast's (the battery drain problem).

Is it possible that i can listen on the "SCREEN_ON" broadcast without a Service?

Jur

**Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<application
    android:name=".Application"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true">

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".services.ScreenOnService" />

    <receiver android:name=".broadcast.receivers.AutoStartReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".broadcast.receivers.ScreenOnReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

**AutoStartReceiver**

```
public class AutoStartReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public void onReceive(Context aContext, Intent anIntent)
    {
        Log.i("[AutoStartReceiver]", "onReceive");
        aContext.startService(new Intent(aContext, ScreenOnService.class));
    }
}
```

**ScreenOnReceiver**

```
public class ScreenOnReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.i("[ScreenOnReceiver]", "onReceive");
    }
}
```

**ScreenOnService**

```
public class ScreenOnService extends IntentService
{
    private ScreenOnReceiver theReceiver;

    public ScreenOnService()
    {
        super(ScreenOnService.class.getName());
        theReceiver = new ScreenOnReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.v("[ScreenOnService]", "onStartCommand");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        Log.i("[ScreenOnService]", "onHandleIntent");
        registerReceiver(theReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));
        while(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        Log.i("[ScreenOnService]", "onDestroy");
        unregisterReceiver(theReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have any particular reason for using an `IntentService` as opposed to a regular started `Service`?

You should be able to achieve this using a regular started `Service`. Register the receiver as part of `onStartCommand`.

Something like this:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private ScreenOnReceiver mReceiver;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (mReceiver == null) {
            mReceiver = new ScreenOnReceiver();
            registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));
        }
        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
        // stopped, so return sticky.
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    // remember to unregister receiver in onDestroy...
}
```

This way you avoid busy looping. `IntentService` is designed to be a short lived service performing a background operation. Your usage does not fit the purpose of `IntentService`.

Comment: Awesome! I was using a IntentService because i only wanted to have 1 active ScreenOnService running. I just dind read the full docs about the Service and IntentService.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I got a broadcast receiver "BOOT_COMPLETED" that starts a sticky IntentService that is registering the "SCREEN_ON" broadcast receiver with a never ending loop to catch to broadcast's (the battery drain problem)

This is completely inappropriate for an `IntentService`. Your problem is that an `IntentService` shuts down after `onHandleIntent()` returns, forcing you into this busy-wait.

Instead, use a regular `Service`.

> Is it possible that i can listen on the "SCREEN_ON" broadcast without a Service?

AFAIK, `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` still cannot be registered for in the manifest, so, yes, you need a `Service`. But you need a `Service`, not an `IntentService`.

Answer (score 0):

> I got a broadcast receiver "BOOT_COMPLETED" that starts a sticky
>   IntentService that is registering the "SCREEN_ON" broadcast receiver
>   with a never ending loop to catch to broadcast's (the battery drain
>   problem).

This is not correct. The intent service is not design for long running operation.Actually It is no longer remain running after `onHandleIntent().`

If you want to listen constantly up to device is turn on then service will sure help you to listen each every trigger.

```
public class ScreenOnService extends Service
{
...........
}
```