# Keep intent service running?

Tags: android, intentservice

I have an intent service that listens for broadcasts (ACTION_SCREEN_ON, ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) but they only work as long as onHandleIntent stays open.  Should I create an infinte loop within onHandleIntent?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android keep intentservice running and listen for broadcasts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807014/android-keep-intentservice-running-and-listen-for-broadcasts)

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular `Service`, please, not an `IntentService`. `IntentService` is designed for transactional bits of work, where the service can then shut down.

Also note that you will need this to be a foreground service (using `startForeground()`) for it to be effective on Android 8.0+.

Comment: But I need this service running even if the app is closed.

Comment: @JamesJohnson: `IntentService` does not help with that. A foreground service does.