# Service, IntentService, or threads for background network I/O

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am creating an app that is basically a tunnel program. My UI has a start/stop button. Start would be to start the service/thread and the networking will happen in the background. I then want to be able to stop the service/thread. I also need to be able to put the app in the background and it continues to work.

I have tried a `Service` and the issue with that is it takes the main thread so the UI is no longer responsive. I have also tried a `IntentService` and the issue with that was the service was not being destroyed when I was trying.

I have not tried a thread because I would have to block and wait for the thread to be completed. If this is done in the main thread, then the UI is frozen. If I do this in a Service if the service returns wouldn't the thread die? If not, how do I communicate to the thread to tell it to stop?

Comment: If you want work to continue in the background then really your only option is a `Service`. A service runs on the UI thread so you will need to offload the work you want done in there to a background thread

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried a Service and the issue with that is it takes the main
> thread so the UI is no longer responsive.

Yes, `Service`s run on the main thread. But you can spawn (multiple) threads from within your `Service`, and then read/write from/to your sockets in these threads, thereby not blocking the UI thread when you do network I/O.

> I have also tried a IntentService and the issue with that was the
> service was not being destroyed when I was trying.

Do not use an `IntentService` for this. `IntentService`s are for [carrying out short-lived background tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32807134/1214974). They shouldn't be used to manage a long-lived network tunnel.

> I have not tried a thread because I would have to block and wait for the thread to be completed.

What do you mean by "completed"? You can spawn and start a thread from the UI thread just fine. The "wait" (overhead involved) in firing up a new thread is not significant enough to interfere with UI responsiveness.

> If I do this in a Service if the service returns wouldn't the thread die? If not, how do I communicate to the thread to tell it to stop?

As far as I know, the thread wouldn't be terminated just because the `Service` is stopped. But you'd lose all means of interacting with the threads because you'd have no reference to them. So this would, among other things, result in a memory leak. What you need to do is use the callbacks that are invoked during the `Service`'s lifecycle to manage your threads. When your `Service` is started, spawn your network worker threads. When your `Service` is being destroyed, terminate your network worker threads.

> [...] how do I communicate to the thread to tell it to stop?

I suggest you use [service binding](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services) to communicate between your `Activity` and your `Service` (s.t. you can make your `Service` start/stop the network worker threads when the user presses the start/stop buttons). However, note that you also want to start your service, not just bind to it, to make it run continuously in the background. A `Service` can be both bound and started, it's not one or the other. You should do both.